# loading other domain page in my app

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

jquery mobile app, how can I load other domain web page

i tried iFrame but then having mobiles size problem

i tried PHP file_get_contents the page load but the internal link/script doesn't work

any idea ??

thanks

here is my code

HTML:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="#home" data-role="button"  data-inline="true" data-icon="home" >home</a>
    <h1>lists</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="listDetail" style="height:100%;width:100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
    var list_url= 'http://lists.php';
    $.ajax({          
        type:  'GET',
        data: {area: areaID },
        url:   list_url,
        dataType: 'html',              
        success: function(result){
            $("#listDetail").html(result);
        }
     });
```

PHP

```
    echo file_get_contents("http://m.booking.com/searchresults.html?aid=123456&lang=en&lang=en&latitude=55&longitude=56&radius=40");
```

Answer (score 0):

The link tag "a" may contains the url like this href="/searchresult....." you can replace all or append all link with like this

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://m.booking.com/searchresults.html?aid=123456&lang=en&lang=en&latitude=55&longitude=56&radius=40");
$content = str_replace ('href="/','href="http://m.booking.com/"',$content);
echo $content;
```

Similarly watch all link and make it correct path

Comment: im getting this error: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://m.booking.com/".

Comment: tag of stylesheet also have the href attribute now you dont need to replace stylesheet href.. try the code again

Comment: im getting the following error:  "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://4228414.fls.doubleclick.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://m.booking.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."